# Faster searching through files in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, file, search, for-loop

I have a problem where my current algorithm uses a naive linear search algorithm to retrieve data from several data files through matching strings.

It is something like this (pseudo code):

```
while count < total number of files
     open current file
     extract line from this file
     build an arrayofStrings from this line

     foreach string in arrayofStrings
          foreach file in arrayofDataReferenceFiles
               search in these files

     close file
     increment count
```

For a large real life job, a process can take about 6 hours to complete.

Basically I have a large set of strings that uses the program to search through the the same set of files (for example 10 in 1 instance and can be 3 in the next instance the program runs). Since the reference data files can change, I do not think it is smart to build a permanent index of these files.

I'm pretty much a beginner and am not aware of any faster techniques for unsorted data.

I was thinking since the search gets repetitive after a while, is it possible to prebuild an index of locations of specific lines in the data reference files without using any external perl libraries once the file array gets built (files are known)? This script is going to be ported onto a server that probably only has standard Perl installed.

I figured it might be worth spending 3-5 minutes building some sort of index for a search before processing the job.

Is there a specific concept of indexing/searching that applies to my situation?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

I assume the data set does not fit in RAM.

If you are trying to match each line in many files against a set of patterns, it may be better to read each line in once, then match it against all the patterns while it's in memory before moving on. This will reduce IO over looping for each pattern.

On the other hand, if the matching is what's taking the time you're probably better off using a library which can simultaneously match lots of patterns.

Comment: Thanks this helped reduced my process time down signficantly by just matching everything while it is still in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably replace this:

```
foreach file in arrayofDataReferenceFiles
    search in these files
```

with a preprocessing step to build a DBM file (i.e. an on-disk hash) as a reverse index which maps each word in your reference files to a list of the files containing that word (or whatever you need). The Perl core [includes DBM support](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html):

> **dbmopen HASH,DBNAME,MASK**
>
> This binds a dbm(3), ndbm(3), sdbm(3), gdbm(3), or Berkeley DB file to a hash.

You'd normally access this stuff through [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) but that's not important, every Perl should have some support for at least one hash-on-disk library without needing non-core packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

As MarkR said, you want to read each line from each file no more than one time.  The pseudocode you posted looks like you're reading each line of each file multiple times (once for each word that is searched for), which will slow things down considerably, especially on large searches.  Reversing the order of the two innermost loops should (judging by the posted pseudocode) fix this.

But, also, you said, "*Since the reference data files can change, I do not think it is smart to build a permanent index of these files.*"  This is, most likely, incorrect.  If performance is a concern (if you're getting 6-hour runtimes, I'd say that probably makes it a concern) and, on average, each file gets read more than once between changes to that particular file, then building an index on disk (or even... using a database!) would be a very smart thing to do.  Disk space is very cheap these days; time that people spend waiting for results is not.

Even if files frequently undergo multiple changes without being read, on-demand indexing (when you want to check the file, first look to see whether an index exists and, if not, build one before doing the search) would be an excellent approach - when a file gets searched more than once, you benefit from the index; when it doesn't, building the index first, then doing an search off the index will be slower than a linear search by such a small margin as to be largely irrelevant.